# How to make Rails not import every file from app/assets/stylesheets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, sass, stylesheet

In app/assets/stylesheets, I have many sass files. In a requested page, every file in app/assets/stylesheets is imported (with a  tag). How do I make it so that not every file from the directory is imported, but only the ones that I pick?

Note: I'm running Rails 4.1.2

Comment: Remove `*= require_tree .` line from your manifest file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You change your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css file.

Instead of `*=require_tree .`

Add:

```
*=require './file1' 
*=require './file2'
...
```

You don't need to supply `.css` or `.css.scss`

Comment: It's app/assets/stylesheets/application.css actually.

Answer (score 0):

**Manifest**

As alluded to by `@Ruby Racer`, you'll be looking to manipulate the [`manifest`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) of your `stylesheets` in your application:

> Sprockets uses manifest files to determine which assets to include and
>   serve. These manifest files contain directives - instructions that
>   tell Sprockets which files to require in order to build a single CSS
>   or JavaScript file.

The way to use this is at the top of any of your `css` files, typically your `application.css` file -

```
/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/* = require "file" */
```

By doing this, you'll be able to build your stylesheet assets as you require

--

**SASS**

If it's only the stylesheets you want to change, you need to remember something else -

If you changed the extension of your CSS to `.css.scss`, you'll be able to call the [`@import`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) function of `SASS` to create a similar effect to the `manifest` functionality:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@import "file"
```